# Lua : Incorrect string length for String with Special Characters

Tags: string, lua, luajit

Consider the two cases below:

```
local str1 = "abc"
```

`str1:len` gives **3**

```
local str2 = "£££"
```

`str2:len` gives **6**

Can someone explain this?

LuaJit version: 5.1

Comment: `local str2len = #str2:gsub("[\128-\191]", "")`

Answer (score 4):

The length of strings in Lua is the number of *bytes* in it, not the number of *chars*.

To handle multibyte charsets, you need a library like `utf8`, which is available in Lua 5.3.

Comment: the issue I am facing is I need to support a string of length 80. So input with characters as '£' are exceeding the length as per lua, but not from the users perspective.

Comment: local function parse_string(str)
  local ret = ""
  local flag = true

  for i = 1, #str do
    local c = str:sub(i,i)
    local char = string.char(b2i.toint(c, "big", false, 1))

    if char > "\127" then
      flag = not flag
      if(flag) then
        ret = ret .. char
      end
    else
      ret = ret .. char
    end
  end

  return ret

end

Comment: @user1681485 If users understand anything about the "length" of text, it would be graphemes and whitespace between visible characters. An artificial limit on your internal representation of their text would be quite difficult to explain precisely.

Comment: An example of using utf8 library would be a great addition to this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

local function parse_string(str)

```
   local ret = ""

   local flag = true

   for i = 1, #str do

             local c = str:sub(i,i)

             local char = string.char(b2i.toint(c, "big", false, 1))


             if char > "\127" then

             flag = not flag

             if(flag) then

                 ret = ret .. char

            end

         else

        ret = ret .. char

    end
```

end

```
  return ret
```

end